# The CheckMarx security scanner says that these lines is a Query: XSRF Error

Tags: apex, visualforce, checkmarx, xsrf

I have a visualforce which is just used to send the Json data when we make a callout to the page with some parameters passed in the URL.
Error is showing in the following line. Please help in get through this issue.

```
<apex:page controller="controllerClass" readOnly="false" contentType="application/json" action="{!StartUpAction}" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" >

update pm;
```

In controller method `ActionMethod()` I am getting the Parameter from the Url and updating an object and then returning the `Json`.

Here is the code of the Page:

```
<apex:page controller="GridJSONService" ... action="{!StartUpAction}">
    <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!Output}" />
</apex:page>
```

Here is the code of the Controller :

```
public with sharing class GridJSONService {

    public GridJSONService () { /* constructor */ }

    public void StartUpAction()
    { 
        // intermediate logic
        Planning_Model__c pm = [Select ID,Comments__c from Planning_Model__c where ID =: u_RowId];
        pm.Comments__c = u_Comment;
        update pm;
        // other logic
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the method code. I am sure that we can't direct access data from parameter. You need to encode them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Performing any DML during a page's action method is a security concern. This is because people can cause your code to run without the user's consent. For example, consider what happens if someone puts this HTML into an email, or a page on a website, etc:

```
<img src="https://na1.visual.force.com/apex/MyPage?id=12345" />
```

Even though no image will appear, the damage has already been done: your DML was performed by the user without them even knowing anything's happened. At minimum, you should consider calling the method after the page loads. Even better, you should **warn** the user and give them a chance to back out.

Comment: I have updated the question with the VF Page code and Controller code.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue. The problem is we cannot use any DML statement in the action method. SO i have moved the DML statements and it passed the checkmarx test.

I have chnaged the controller as follows:

```
public with sharing class GridJSONService {

public GridJSONService () { /* constructor */ }

public void StartUpAction()
{ 
    // intermediate logic
    Planning_Model__c pm = [Select ID,Comments__c from Planning_Model__c where ID =: u_RowId];
    pm.Comments__c = u_Comment;
    //update pm;
    performDML(JSON.serialize(pm), 'true');
    // other logic
}

@future
public static void performDML(String obj, String isUpdate) {
    if(isUpdate == 'true') {
        update (Planning_Model__c) JSON.deserialize(obj, Planning_Model__c.class);
    } else {
        insert (Planning_Model__c) JSON.deserialize(obj, Planning_Model__c.class);
    }
}

}
```

This solved the problem.

Comment: So basically the already posted answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)? It would be more useful to the community if you instead [accept that answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered.

Comment: Now the answer is complete as i have mentioned the perfect solution which solved the problem(by using future method).